# How to alter powershell command line for mongodb export into a Powershell script (for scheduled task purposes)

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I'm not a coder but trying to help my development team by taking on simple tasks myself, one of which is to set up a Windows scheduled task to export components of our mongodb through Powershell. With help from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/import-export/ and some trial and error (as well as a bit of troubleshooting help from dev friends), I've been able to write some Powershell command lines that successfully export the relevant Mongodb collections when manually executed within Powershell:

```
cd c:\mongobinlocation

.\mongoexport --db db --collection collection1 --jsonArray --out "\\server\archivelocation\collection1.json"

.\mongoexport --db db --collection collection2 --jsonArray --out "\\server\archivelocation\collection2.json"

.\mongoexport --db db --collection collection3 --jsonArray --out "\\server\archivelocation\collection3.json"
```

However, I then set upon trying to set up a scheduled task to run the script in Powershell (using instructions here: http://www.ilovepowershell.com/how-to-run-powershell-script-as-scheduled-task/)
 and realized that the Powershell command lines that I have set up do not equate to a Powershell script that can be run in a scheduled task. I'm looking for a basic template example that I could modify to insert my command lines above and I've had no luck- everything I see looks drastically different than my little ol' command lines. Is there any way to wrap the above commands into something basic or do I have to start from scratch and learn how to write a Powershell script?

Thanks for any and all help, and I appreciate your time!

Comment: What you've written would be fine in a `.bat` file - there don't appear to be any PowerShell commands in there. You can just save your file as a `.bat`, then create a scheduled task to run it - no template required!

Comment: Thanks so much, Simon- this was exactly what I needed to know. I did exactly as you directed and it appears to be working perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Scheduled tasks at all. I need to learn them. Since I know nothing about scheduling tasks I put my scheduling in my PowerShell scripts.

```
While($true){ #Easily replaced by a for-loop
    ... #your script
    Start-Sleep (60*60*24)
    #I prefer to use "timeout /t <seconds>"
}
```

If you throw this on a server that doesn't get restarted you have a easy scheduled task. If you're really looking to learn check out Workflows with PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I'll go with the .bat file proposed by Simon above, but I appreciate your comment and will keep it in mind in the future- I am indeed looking to increase my knowledge level and I'm sure this will be handy in the future. Thanks again!